# Send excel file from angular js to spring API rest

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Since i am a beginner in angular js i did not find a way to upload a file  from my computer  and send it to the spring server  using angularJS

However i have developped an API rest with spring boot that can read the file and store it in the database table but i need a UI

So all i need is the angular controller and service

thanks in advance and i appreciate any possible help with the angular controller 
here is my html code

```
    <input type="file" name="file" 

    id="fileUpload" file-model="myFile" title="ChooseYour file"/> 


   <button value="Upload" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
    ng-click="UploadExcel()"></button>
```

Comment: you may wanna give it a try:[`ng-file-upload`](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: From your view, you should fire one function declared in your controller called UploadExcel(). That function should be inject your service that makes a POST request to your API Rest

Comment: can you please give me an example of the code Mr Jonathan